# React-Native "react-native run-ios"

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I installed a fresh react-native app.I keep getting the below error when I ran `react-native run-ios`

```
Incorrect hash:

eb7c61ff0c1c55cd85deb3c15f2731c14c787429 ?/Users/johndoe/.rncache/boost_1_63_0.tar.gz
```

I have tried `react-native upgrade`, `rm -rf node_modules`

Still doesn't work.

Comment: Try to delete `.rncache` with `rm -rf ~/.rncache`.

Comment: Also, is this a small part of a larger output? Might help to post the whole output. I had this issue because of a library file wasn't loaded in the past.

Comment: @ReyHaynes I tried `rm -rf ~/.rncache` and run the "react-native run ios" but the app is still not showing up on the emulator

Comment: Could you add the full output of the error?

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

```
rm -rf ~/.rncache
```

then re-run it.

```
react-native run-ios
```

if it's still not showing the simulator, then you could try to add `--simulator="iPhone 6s"`

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 6s"
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this command to freshen up everything and pray twice facing the north.

```
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache verify && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check this error using simulator app and real device.
2. Upgrade Xcode to currently latest version.

Otherwise use `create-react-native-app`. That way you can run app both device and simulator, which is great case if you don't need to detach your app.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolve it, this problem is the version of boost wrong in start scripts.

1. Go to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.56-stable/scripts/ios-install-third-party.sh and select the branch your rn version.
2. Drag to the bottom and go to the `url` such as https://github.com/react-native-community/boost-for-react-native/releases/download/v1.63.0-0/boost_1_63_0.tar.gz
3. Copy the download file to `~/.rncache`, replace the old one.
4. Restart.

Done!